# how add buffering or loading in MoviePlayer Swift Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift

i am trying add loading or buffering to moviePlayer before load movie and i tried with alert but didn't work

see the code

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "moviePlayBackStateChanged:", name: "MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification",object:  moviePlayer)


    func moviePlayBackStateChanged(notification:NSNotification)
{

    var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Loading", message: "test loading", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "CLose")
    alert.show()

}
```